# rails 4 article data template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, associations

e.g. i have two models generated with scaffold, `Template` and `Article`

`Template has_many :articles` and `Article belong_to :template`

`Template` have `title:string body:text` as fields. 
`Article` have `title:string body:text template_id:integer` as fields.

The question is: how i can use the `Template` model to prefill the `Article`'s fields when one new is created?

Comment: are you wanting the models to have duplicate data?

Comment: One model is the base of another, perhaps a better example would be to create letters based on a template, instead of articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the logic in an `before_create` callback

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template

  before_create :assign_attributes_from_template


  def assign_attributes_from_template
    title = template.title
    # etc
  end
end
```

This will however run *after* validation, so if you need to validate these fields you should probably put this in a `before_validation, on: :create` callback instead.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** [Link to callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) guide

Comment: you refer to [hooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) but i think you mean [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. I wrote this before having coffee this morning. I do in fact mean callbacks. Will update my answer. Thanks